# How to deal with side effects produced by async/await when it comes to mutable value types?

Tags: c#, struct, async-await

Please, consider the following example code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public struct AStruct
{
    public int Value;

    public async Task SetValueAsync()
    {
        Value = await Task.Run(() => 1);
    }
    public void SetValue()
    {
        Value = 1;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(new AStruct());
        TestAsync(new AStruct()).Wait();
    }

    private static async Task TestAsync(AStruct x)
    {
        Debug.Assert(x.Value == 0);
        await x.SetValueAsync();
        Debug.Assert(x.Value == 0);
    }

    private static void Test(AStruct x)
    {
        Debug.Assert(x.Value == 0);
        x.SetValue();
        Debug.Assert(x.Value == 1);
    }
}
```

Notice the difference between `Test` and `TestAsync`. This code satisfies all the assertions.

I guess looking at the code with Reflector will tell me why, but still this is something I did not expect at all.

Of course, changing `AStruct` to be a class instead of a struct does fail the second assertion in `TestAsync` - as I would expect it in the first place.

My question is this - besides not using mutable structs with async/await is there an elegant way to make them coexist peacefully?

Comment: Mutating a value type when it is a parameter (without `ref`) is totally nonsensical. Async does not even come into this picture.

Comment: @leppie The issue is that `SetValueAsync` doesn't mutate the variable that calls it, and it doesn't do so precisely because it's an `async` method.  The fact that it's called on a variable that's a parameter that's not passed by `ref` isn't relevant at all.  The mutation fails to even mutate the copy that `TestAsync` makes of the struct created in `Main`.

Comment: @Servy: Guess the same will go for a generator (and probably when using it a free variable).

Comment: [Mutable value types are evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx) - regardless of whether you're using `async`/`await`. Also, asynchronous code is inherently functional, so dealing with side effects at all is a bit awkward (it's usually cleaner to *return* a composite result instead of having the `async` method *update* values as a side effect).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's inherently impossible for an `async` method of a `struct` to mutate "itself".

This of course makes complete sense when you think about it.  By the time the whatever tasks you `await` inside of that struct actually finish, given that you've returned to the caller and allowed them to continue on doing all sorts of things, you have no way of ensuring that the actual struct instance that called the method even exists any more.  If `SetValueAsync` was called on a local variable by a method that didn't `await` it or `Wait` on it or anything like that then that local variable's lifetime will likely have ended by the time `SetValueAsync` reaches the continuation of it's call to `Run`.  It can't mutate the variable who's lifetime may or may not be in scope.  The only option here is for `async` methods of a struct to effectively copy themselves when the method is called and have the code in the continuation reference an entirely different variable that the variable that called the `async`.  Since the method is making a copy that won't be accessible anywhere other than the body of this `async` method, it means that, for all intents an purposes, an `async` method of a struct can never mutate that struct (and have the mutation be visible by anyone else).

You can have an `async` method of a mutable `struct`, so long as that method itself isn't expected to mutate the `struct`.  That one method will need to return a `Task<T>` with a new struct, or something equivalent.

As an interesting tanget, it's within the bounds of technical possibility for an `async` method of a `struct` to mutate itself *before the first `await` of the method* if it really wanted to.  The compiler chooses to take the copy right away, so this isn't actually possible, but the explicit choice was made to make the copy at the very start of the method rather than only after the first `await`.  This is probably for the best, whether it was an intentional decision or not, as it would be super confusing otherwise.