# What causes a struct in C# to reset its values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, struct, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 based project written in C#. I have the following `struct` object that I am trying to call using a middleware.

```
internal struct StaticAsyncFileContext
{
    private const int StreamCopyBufferSize = 64 * 1024;
    private readonly HttpContext _context;
    private readonly StaticAsyncFileOptions _options;
    private readonly HttpRequest _request;
    private readonly HttpResponse _response;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IAsyncFileProvider _fileProvider;
    private readonly IContentTypeProvider _contentTypeProvider;
    private string _method;
    private bool _isGet;
    private PathString _subPath;
    private string _contentType;
    private IFileInfo _fileInfo;

    private long _length;
    private DateTimeOffset _lastModified;
    private EntityTagHeaderValue _etag;

    private RequestHeaders _requestHeaders;
    private ResponseHeaders _responseHeaders;

    private PreconditionState _ifMatchState;
    private PreconditionState _ifNoneMatchState;
    private PreconditionState _ifModifiedSinceState;
    private PreconditionState _ifUnmodifiedSinceState;

    private RangeItemHeaderValue _range;

    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo()
    {
        return _fileInfo;
    }

    public StaticAsyncFileContext(HttpContext context, StaticAsyncFileOptions options, PathString matchUrl, IAsyncFileProvider fileProvider, IContentTypeProvider contentTypeProvider)
    {
        _context = context;
        _options = options;
        _request = context.Request;
        _response = context.Response;
        _requestHeaders = _request.GetTypedHeaders();
        _responseHeaders = _response.GetTypedHeaders();
        _fileProvider = fileProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(fileProvider)} cannot be null.");
        _contentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(contentTypeProvider)} cannot be null.");
        _subPath = PathString.Empty;
        _method = null;
        _contentType = null;
        _fileInfo = null;
        _length = 0;
        _etag = null;
         _range = null;

        _isGet = false;
        IsHeadMethod = false;
        IsRangeRequest = false;

        _lastModified = new DateTimeOffset();
        _ifMatchState = PreconditionState.Unspecified;
        _ifNoneMatchState = PreconditionState.Unspecified;
        _ifModifiedSinceState = PreconditionState.Unspecified;
        _ifUnmodifiedSinceState = PreconditionState.Unspecified;           
    }

    internal enum PreconditionState
    {
        Unspecified,
        NotModified,
        ShouldProcess,
        PreconditionFailed
    }

    public bool IsHeadMethod { get; private set; }

    public bool IsRangeRequest { get; private set; }

    public string SubPath
    {
        get { return _subPath.Value; }
    }

    public async Task<bool> LookupFileInfoAsync()
    {
        _fileInfo = await _fileProvider.GetFileInfoAsync(_subPath.Value);
        if (_fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            _length = _fileInfo.Length;

            DateTimeOffset last = _fileInfo.LastModified;
            // Truncate to the second.
            _lastModified = new DateTimeOffset(last.Year, last.Month, last.Day, last.Hour, last.Minute, last.Second, last.Offset).ToUniversalTime();

            long etagHash = _lastModified.ToFileTime() ^ _length;
            _etag = new EntityTagHeaderValue('\"' + Convert.ToString(etagHash, 16) + '\"');
        }
        return _fileInfo.Exists;
    }

    public void ApplyResponseHeaders(int statusCode)
    {
        // Here _fileInfo should not be null since it was set by LookupFileInfoAsync()

        _response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        if (statusCode < 400)
        {
            // these headers are returned for 200, 206, and 304
            // they are not returned for 412 and 416
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_contentType))
            {
                _response.ContentType = _contentType;
            }
            _responseHeaders.LastModified = _lastModified;
            _responseHeaders.ETag = _etag;
            _responseHeaders.Headers[HeaderNames.AcceptRanges] = "bytes";
        }
        if (statusCode == Constants.Status200Ok)
        {
            // this header is only returned here for 200
            // it already set to the returned range for 206
            // it is not returned for 304, 412, and 416
            _response.ContentLength = _length;
        }

        _options.OnPrepareResponse(new StaticFileResponseContext(_context, _fileInfo));
    }

    public Task SendStatusAsync(int statusCode)
    {
        ApplyResponseHeaders(statusCode);

        _logger.LogHandled(statusCode, SubPath);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public PreconditionState GetPreconditionState()
    {
        return GetMaxPreconditionState(_ifMatchState, _ifNoneMatchState, _ifModifiedSinceState, _ifUnmodifiedSinceState);
    }

    public async Task SendAsync()
    {
        ApplyResponseHeaders(Constants.Status200Ok);
        string physicalPath = _fileInfo.PhysicalPath;
        var sendFile = _context.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>();
        if (sendFile != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(physicalPath))
        {
            // We don't need to directly cancel this, if the client disconnects it will fail silently.
            await sendFile.SendFileAsync(physicalPath, 0, _length, CancellationToken.None);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            using (var readStream = _fileInfo.CreateReadStream())
            {
                // Larger StreamCopyBufferSize is required because in case of FileStream readStream isn't going to be buffering
                await StreamCopyOperation.CopyToAsync(readStream, _response.Body, _length, StreamCopyBufferSize, _context.RequestAborted);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogWriteCancelled(ex);
            // Don't throw this exception, it's most likely caused by the client disconnecting.
            // However, if it was cancelled for any other reason we need to prevent empty responses.
            _context.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above `struct` when the method `LookupFileInfoAsync()` is invoked, it suppose to set the value of `_fileInfo`, `_length` and `_lastModified` properties. If the method `GetPreconditionState()` or `GetFileInfo()` are called after `LookupFileInfoAsync()`, the value of `_fileInfo` should NOT be null if `_fileInfo.Exists` returns true.

Here is how my middleware invokes this `struct`

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var fileContext = new StaticAsyncFileContext(context, _options, _matchUrl, _logger, _fileProvider, _contentTypeProvider);

    if (!await fileContext.LookupFileInfoAsync())
    {
        _logger.LogFileNotFound(fileContext.SubPath);
    } else {

        // This is an unesassary line, it is only added to ensure that FileInfo was set
        IFileInfo fileInfo = fileContext.GetFileInfo();

        switch (fileContext.GetPreconditionState())
        {
            case StaticAsyncFileContext.PreconditionState.Unspecified:
            case StaticAsyncFileContext.PreconditionState.ShouldProcess:
                if (fileContext.IsHeadMethod)
                {
                    await fileContext.SendStatusAsync(Constants.Status200Ok);
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    await fileContext.SendAsync();
                    _logger.LogFileServed(fileContext.SubPath, fileContext.PhysicalPath);
                    return;
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    context.Response.Clear();
                }
                break;
            //... stripped out for simplicity

            default:
                var exception = new NotImplementedException(fileContext.GetPreconditionState().ToString());
                Debug.Fail(exception.ToString());
                throw exception;
        }
    }

    await _next(context);
}
```

As you can see that `LookupFileInfoAsync()` is called first and that ensures that `_infoFile` property is NOT null since it returned true. But in my case, calling `fileContext.GetFileInfo()` after calling `LookupFileInfoAsync()` return null. When stepping through my code I can differently see that `_fileInfo` is being set correctly. But on the next method call, the value of `_fileInfo` will be reset to null somehow. If you look at Microsoft's [StaticFileContext.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/StaticFileContext.cs) file, you'll notice that the code is very similar except that `LookupFileInfo()` called is being called asynchronously in my case.

**Question**

What could be causing the `_fileInfo` property to reset to null after `LookupFileInfoAsync()` is called?

Comment: The [Microsoft guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) say that structs should not exceed 16 bytes, and should be immutable. Yours is *massive*, and mutable. Are you sure you don't want a class there?

Comment: You're hitting this: [Struct's private field value is not updated using an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642535/structs-private-field-value-is-not-updated-using-an-async-method/31646624#31646624). Turn your struct into a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, it's ideal if structs are *immutable*. This single rule would most likely fix your problem.

**Secondly** `structs` are *value types*, which means you are copying them a lot of the times (not the reference to them).

Just like any other *value types*, if you make copies of them, the changes are independent of the other copies

[Structs (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs)

> Structs are copied on assignment. When a struct is assigned to a new
>   variable, all the data is copied, and any modification to the new copy
>   does not change the data for the original copy. This is important to
>   remember when working with collections of value types such as
>   `Dictionary<string, myStruct>`.

Comment: `fileContext` is only being assigned once though, I don't see anywhere that it would get copied.

Comment: @yaakov async and await does does all sorts of magical things

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as @yaakov, So are you saying here I should not use `struct` rather a class since `async` operation copies the values instead of referencing them?

Comment: @John yeah basically if you stick by the immutable struct paradigm you don't get this problem by default. Change it to a class and you are on your way